# React | Virtual DOM Modal is not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, virtual-dom

I'm using [React JS](https://reactjs.org/) and [Ant Design](https://ant.design/) for my project.

**Problem**

I'm creating virtual DOM element. It has `Popover` In that there is `Button` and then clicking that showing `Modal`.

It showing error `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

**JS Code**

```
content = (
  <div className="RecurringPopover"> 
    <button onClick={this.showModal}> Show Modal </button> 
  </div>
);
```

**Full Code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ql4wwo)**

Comment: @Striped. Click button inside popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the method to the proper scope:

```
content = (
  <div className="RecurringPopover"> 
    <button onClick={this.showModal.bind(this)}> Show Modal </button> 
  </div>
);
```

Comment: @MariaJeysinghAnbu Use the `visible` and `onVisibleChange` props as detailed in the documentation. **Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hk6f7r?file=index.js | **Docs:** https://ant.design/components/popover/

Comment: How I suppose to do when I have muliple popover in page https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wfaivz?file=index.js

Comment: This is getting out of topic, but you would need to have different properties in your state object and handle them separately.

Answer (score 0):

add on your constructor

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this)
    this.state = {
        // hereyour state
    };
}
```

or

```
onClick={this.showModal.bind(this)}
```

To close or open the modal you can do this

```
 showModal() {
    this.setState({
        modal: !this.state.modal
    });
}
```

Comment: How I suppose to hide popover when Modal opened.

Comment: you want to close the modal ?